# Existence of a harmonic function?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian

[image]

I really have no clue about this problem. Should I represent $u(x)$ using $\varphi(x')$? But how to represent that?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you familiar with [Poisson integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel#On_the_upper_half-space)?